# Verifying a Series Solution to Dirichlet's Problem via separation of variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

In Stein's Fourier Analysis i'm having trouble attempting to verify the series solution given in the problem in $(1.)$

$(1.)$

The Dirchlet problem is the annulus defined by ${{(r, \theta): p < r < 1}}$, where $0 \leq p \leq 1$ in the inner radius. The problem to solve:

$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{r}^{2}} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}+ \frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{\theta}^{2}} = 0$$

subject to the boundary conditions:

$${
     \begin{align} 
       u(1,\theta) = f(\theta) \\
       u(p,\theta) = g(\theta). 
     \end{align}
 }$$
Stein's intial argument was to write solutions for the Dirchlet Problem as he did previously in the following form:

$$u(r,\theta)= \sum_{}^{}c_{n}(r)e^{in\theta}$$

with $c_{n}(r) = A_{n}r^{n} + B_{n}r^{-n}, n \neq 0$ Set: 
$$f(\theta) \sim \sum_{}^{} a_{n}e^{in\theta}$$ and

$$g(\theta) \sim \sum_{}^{}b_{n}e^{in\theta}$$

This leads to the solution

$$u(r,\theta) = \sum_{n \leq 0} (\frac{1}{p^{n}-p^{-n}})((p/r)^{n} - (r/p)^{n})a_{n} + (r^{n} - r^{-n})b_{n}]e^{in\theta} + a_{o} + (b_{o} - a_{o}\frac{logr}{logp}$$

From looking what was done in Chapter 1 as a prior example,  and comparing the problem in $(1.)$the series the solution was obtained via Sepration of Variables. My initial attack can be followed in $(2.)$

$(2.)$

$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{r}^{2}} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}+ \frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{\theta}^{2}} = \Delta{u}$$
$$r^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{r}^{2}} +  r\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}} = -\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{\theta}^{2}}$$

Plugging in our solution product: $(u(r,\theta))=F(r)G(\theta))$
$$r^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{r}^{2}}F(r)G(\theta) +  r\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}F(r)G(\theta)= -\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{\theta}^{2}}F(r)G(\theta)$$

Now dividing by our Solution Product:
 $$\frac{r^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{r}^{2}}F(r)G(\theta) + r\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}F(r)G(\theta) } {F{(r)}} = \frac{-\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{\theta}^{2}}F(r)G(\theta)}{G{(\theta)}} $$

Finally one can observe in a more convenient form  that we have the following:

$$\frac{r^{2}F(r)G''(\theta)+r(G(\theta))F'(r)}{F(r)} = \frac{F(r)-G''(\theta)}{G(\theta)}$$

$$
  \left\{
     \begin{align} 
        r^2G''(\theta) + r(G(\theta)F'(r)) = 0 \\ 
        F(r) - \dfrac{F(r) - G''(\theta)}{G(\theta)} = 0
     \end{align} 
  \right. 
$$

$$   \left\{
     \begin{align}
        r^{2}G''(\theta)+r(G(\theta))F'(r)\lambda F(r)=0 \\
        F(r) - \lambda \frac{G''(\theta)}{G''(\theta)} = 0
     \end{align} 
  \right. 
$$
From the previous result above I'm stuck on working out a series solution to the above ODE's is their any fundamental observations I'm missing towards the problem ?

Comment: The solution to the homogeneous problem usually involves. Easel Functiona.  See "Heat Conduction" by M.N. Ozisik.

Comment: Intersting, In Stein's textbook he gives the solution written as the series: $u(r,\theta) = \sum_{n \leq 0} (\frac{1}{p^{n}-p^{-n}})((p/r)^{n} - (r/p)^{n})a_{n} + (r^{n} - r^{-n})b_{n}]e^{in\theta} + a_{o} + (b_{o} - a_{o}\frac{logr}{logp}$ i'm still trying to figure out how he initially derived it ?

Comment: That should have been Bessel Functions in my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The general solution of the $\ds{2D}$-*Laplace Equation* is given by

\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{r,\theta} & =
\pars{A\,{\theta \over 2\pi} + B}\bracks{C\ln\pars{r \over p} + D}
\\[5mm] & +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left\{\bracks{%
A_{n}\pars{r \over p}^{n} +
B_{n}\pars{p \over r}^{n}}\sin\pars{n\theta}\right.
\\[3mm] & \left.\phantom{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\!\!\braces{}}+
\bracks{%
C_{n}\pars{r \over p}^{n} +
D_{n}\pars{p \over r}^{n}}\cos\pars{n\theta}\right\}\label{1.a}\tag{1.a}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{A, B, C, D, \braces{A_{n}}, \braces{B_{n}}, \braces{C_{n}}\ \mbox{and}\ \braces{D_{n}}}$ are constants which are determined by the boundary conditions.

Since the solution must be invariant under $\ds{\theta \mapsto \theta + 2\pi}$, I'll conclude that $\ds{A = 0}$. In such a case, $\ds{B}$ is 'redundant' such that I can set $\ds{B = 1}$. \eqref{1.a} is reduced to:
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{r,\theta} & =
C\ln\pars{r \over p} + D +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left\{\bracks{%
A_{n}\pars{r \over p}^{n} +
B_{n}\pars{p \over r}^{n}}\sin\pars{n\theta}\right.
\\[3mm] & \left.\phantom{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\!\!\braces{}AAAAAAAAAAA\,}+
\bracks{%
C_{n}\pars{r \over p}^{n} +
D_{n}\pars{p \over r}^{n}}\cos\pars{n\theta}\right\}
\label{1.b}\tag{1.b}
\end{align}

Then,
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{\theta} & =
-C\ln\pars{p} + D +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\pars{A_{n}p^{-n} + B_{n}p^{n}}\sin\pars{n\theta} +
\pars{C_{n}p^{-n} + D_{n}p^{n}}\sin\pars{n\theta}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[2mm]
\mrm{g}\pars{\theta} & = D +
 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\pars{A_{n} + B_{n}}\sin\pars{n\theta} +
\pars{C_{n} + D_{n}}\sin\pars{n\theta}}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

> Integrating both members of \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} over $\ds{\pars{0,2\pi}}$:

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{-\ln\pars{p}C} & \ds{+} & \ds{D} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mrm{f}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}
\\[2mm]
 && \ds{D} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mrm{g}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

> Those relations determines $\ds{C\ \mbox{and}\ D}$.

Similarly,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mrm{f}\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{n\theta}\,{\dd\theta \over \pi} & =
A_{n}p^{-n} + B_{n}p_{n}
\\[2mm]
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mrm{f}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{n\theta}\,{\dd\theta \over \pi} & =
C_{n}p^{-n} + D_{n}p_{n}
\\[2mm]
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mrm{g}\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{n\theta}\,{\dd\theta \over \pi} & =
A_{n} + B_{n}
\\[2mm]
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mrm{g}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{n\theta}\,{\dd\theta \over \pi} & =
C_{n} + D_{n}
\end{align}

> Those equations determine $\ds{\braces{A_{n}},\braces{B_{n}},\braces{C_{n}}\ \mbox{and}\ \braces{D_{n}}}$.

Comment: Interesting approach, I didn't realize this was a valid approach, are there other ways of validating a general solution for a PDE.

Comment: @Zophikel I guess this is the straightforward way because we know, at the very beginning, what is the general solution. If you make 'variable separation' you arrive to that expression $\left(1.a\right)$. So, we never do that because we already know we'll arrive to it anyway. Usually, we know something else for $\,\mathrm{f}\ \mbox{and}\ \,\mathrm{g}$
$\left(~symmetries,\ etc,\ \ldots~\right)$ which enables further simplifications of the solutions $\mathsf{before}$ we impose the boundary conditions.

Comment: Ahhh ok now I understand this is my first time dealing with PDE in Stein's Analysis text, so when dealing with verifying  general solutionsPDE one should simplify our general solution before imposing boundary conditions.